# Run Excel Macro from Task Scheduler / SQL Server JOB

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have an Excel macro that works when I run it in Excel, but I want to run this macro from either task scheduler or a SQL server job (using cscript I guess). I have the following VBS:

```
  Sub RefreshAllExcelInFolder()
    Dim fso
    Dim ObjFolder
    Dim ObjFiles
    Dim ObjFile
    Dim objExcel

    'Creating File System Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Getting the Folder Object
    Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("D:\Source Files\")

    'Getting the list of Files
    Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files
        'On Error Resume Next
        For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
            If LCase(Right(ObjFile.Name, 5)) = ".xlsx" Or LCase(Right(ObjFile.Name, 4)) = ".xls" Then
                Workbooks.Open(ObjFile).Activate
                RefreshAllData
            End If
        Next
End Sub

Sub RefreshAllData()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
   ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    ''''''''MsgBox ("Going back In")
End Sub
```

How can I run this from Task Scheduler / SQL Server Agent? It needs to open Excel somehow first. What should I add to the code to do that?

Comment: Sorry - I really need to read the question all the way to the end, rather than stopping once I see the problems in the code.  `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` and then make sure that all references to objects that are part of the Excel application are qualified - e.g. `objExcel.ActiveWorkbook`.  (And you will probably need to pass `objExcel` as a parameter to `RefreshAllData` so that it can be accessed within that procedure too.)

Comment: Make an excel workbook with an autorun macro, then start excel with the sheet from the external application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion @paul

This is what I did:

1. Open an excel workbook
2. Press Alt+F11 to open VBA Editor
3. Double click on ThisWorkbook from Project Explorer
4. Copy the below code and Paste in the code window
5. Change the folder location
6. Save the file as macro enabled workbook
7. Open the workbook to test it, it will Run a Macro Automatically.

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Dim fso
       Dim ObjFolder
       Dim ObjFiles
       Dim ObjFile
       Dim objExcel

       'Creating File System Object
       Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       'Getting the Folder Object
       Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("O:\DATA\Source Files\")

       'Getting the list of Files
       Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files
           'On Error Resume Next
           For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
               If LCase(Right(ObjFile.Name, 5)) = ".xlsx" Or 
        LCase(Right(ObjFile.Name, 4)) = ".xls" Then
                   Workbooks.Open(ObjFile).Activate
                   RefreshAllData
               End If
           Next
   End Sub
   ```

   Sub RefreshAllData()
       ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
       ActiveWorkbook.Save
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
   End Sub